# How to author content on a Facebook Page as a Facebook User, and not the Page name

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, author

1. Consider a facebook *User* — **MB**, one of the **admins** of a facebook *Page* — [**BDU**](https://www.facebook.com/bigdatauniversity).
2. He's loggin in in as MB
3. He's going to the BDU Page
4. He's writing a *Post* here: it appears as authored by BDU
5. He's adding a *Comment* to the previous Post: it appears as authored by BDU!

Switching the *Use Facebook as:* option does not influence the who appears as authoring the comments:

[image: Authoring on a Facebook Page]

**Q:** How can MB comment on a post on the BDU page, and have the post display as authored by MB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Edit Page settings page:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/edit/?id=YOURPAGEID

Click on "Your Settings" on the left and untick the first box marked "Always comment and post on your page as PAGENAME"

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! As a note, if you don't know `YOURPAGEID`, just go to *Admin Panel » Manage » Edit Page » Your Settings*.